# Problems encountered with label_new feature

Tags: label, alignment, pine-script

I am encountering small issues with using label_new. I have a simple program that draws hline using line.new 2/3 levels below and above current price. To display price, (since line.new doesn't have features to display price on priceline directly), I have used label_new.
While doing this, the labels overlap and are not displayed correctly.(only displaying on right side of chart). If I try to use the feature to display on left side, it gets cut and basically doesn't help. There is no center feature on label_new.

Is there a work around ?